# What is the exact return value of Intl.NumberFormat with the ar locale

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, internationalization

I'm currently writing some unit test and I just get the test to work with the arab locale.

```
const value = new Intl.NumberFormat('fa', {minimumIntegerDigits: 4, minimumFractionDigits: 2, style:'percent'}).format(1.2);
expect(value).toEqual('۰٬۱۲۰٫۰۰‎٪‎');
```

Which fails with the best kind of errors :

```
Expected '٠٬١٢٠٫٠٠٪؜' to equal '۰٬۱۲۰٫۰۰‎٪‎'.
```

Can someone help get the correct string for the expectation ?
This very likely related with use of the Left-to-Right Mark character (U+200E)

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help get the correct string for the expectation?

If you need exact values, you must provide your own serialization implementation instead of relying on the `Intl` API.

Formatted strings produced by the [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) APIs are both implementation- and language-dependent, so they are not appropriate for use cases which require conformance to exact schemas.

I will inline [§4.4 from the ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-implementation-dependencies) for accessibility purposes:

> ### 4.4 Implementation Dependencies
>
> Due to the nature of internationalization, this specification has to leave several details implementation dependent:
>
> - *The set of locales that an implementation supports with adequate localizations:* Linguists estimate the number of human languages to around 6000, and the more widely spoken ones have variations based on regions or other parameters. Even large locale data collections, such as the Common Locale Data Repository, cover only a subset of this large set. Implementations targeting resource-constrained devices may have to further reduce the subset.
> - *The exact form of localizations such as format patterns:* In many cases locale-dependent conventions are not standardized, so different forms may exist side by side, or they vary over time. Different internationalization libraries may have implemented different forms, without any of them being actually wrong. In order to allow this API to be implemented on top of existing libraries, such variations have to be permitted.
> - *Subsets of Unicode:* Some operations, such as collation, operate on strings that can include characters from the entire Unicode character set. However, both the Unicode Standard and the ECMAScript standard allow implementations to limit their functionality to subsets of the Unicode character set. In addition, locale conventions typically don't specify the desired behaviour for the entire Unicode character set, but only for those characters that are relevant for the locale. While the Unicode Collation Algorithm combines a default collation order for the entire Unicode character set with the ability to tailor for local conventions, subsets and tailorings still result in differences in behaviour.